# Cherrypy: multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cherrypy

I launch my Cherrypy code as

```
python -u myApp.py
```

It works fine. However, when I do `ps ax | grep myApp` I can see 21 copies of `python -u myApp.py` running. Why is this and what is this for?

Comment: It has a built in webserver that starts children to handle connections much like Apache.

Comment: Are you using the multiprocessing module in your code?

Comment: Plz, post your code. Cherrypy has one socket listener thread and multiple threads that handle the requests. Your code must be starting processes. Are you listening to multiple ports? Are you using Apache https? Multiple processes are useful only for CPU intensive task, not for handling quick HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

CherryPy uses multiple threads to handle connections. You can control how many it uses by editing the [ThreadPool](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/wsgiserver/init.html?highlight=thread#cherrypy.wsgiserver.ThreadPool) settings.

There are some details on how the worker thread works [in the WSGI docs](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/wsgiserver/init.html):

> - The server’s listening thread runs a very tight loop, sticking incoming connections onto a Queue
> - Worker threads are kept in a pool and poll the Queue, popping off and then handling each connection
> - Each connection can consist of an arbitrary number of requests and their responses

You could probably lower the number of threads in the thread pool if you really don't want to use them, but that may lower performance.